# Como utilizar argc e argv em um terminal windows?

Tags: c, windows, stack, argumento

Estou criando uma pilha para verificação de expressão válida, porém deve-se utilizar nesta `int main( int argc, char **argv )` para entrada. Compilei e não deu erro algum, porém não consigo criar um arquivo executável através do prompt. E já forcei a criação de um através do devc++, mas ao fazer o teste no terminal o programa para de funcionar. Já tentei colocar o argumento entre aspas simples mas o programa também é morto dessa forma.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define TNOME 100

    struct nodoPilha {
        char nome [TNOME];
        struct nodoPilha *proximoPtr;
    };

    typedef struct nodoPilha NodoPilha;
    typedef NodoPilha *NodoPilhaPtr;

    void imprimePilha( NodoPilhaPtr atualPtr );
    int ehVazia( NodoPilhaPtr headPtr );
    void pop( NodoPilhaPtr *headPtr );
    void push( NodoPilhaPtr *headPtr, char nome[TNOME] );





    int main( int argc, char **argv ){
        NodoPilhaPtr headPtr = NULL;
        int h;
        char *aux;
        int i = 1;
        while (i < argc){
            i++;
            h = ehVazia(headPtr);
            if (h){
                push (&headPtr, argv[i]);           
                aux = argv [i]; 
            }
            else {
                if (aux != argv [i]){
                    pop (&headPtr);
                    char aux;
                }
                else {
                    push (&headPtr, argv [i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (h){
            printf ("Valida");
        }
        else {
            printf ("Nao Valida");
        }


    }

    void push( NodoPilhaPtr *headPtr, char nome[TNOME] ){
        char * novalinha = strchr(nome, '\n');
        if (novalinha)
            *novalinha = '\0';  

        NodoPilhaPtr newPtr; 
        newPtr=malloc(sizeof(NodoPilha));

        if ( newPtr != NULL ) { 
            newPtr->proximoPtr = *headPtr;
            strcpy( newPtr->nome,nome);

            *headPtr = newPtr;

        } 
        else {
            printf( "%c nao foi inserido. Memoria nao foi disponibilizada.\n", nome );
        } 
    } 
    void pop( NodoPilhaPtr *headPtr ) {
        NodoPilhaPtr tempPtr; 

        tempPtr = *headPtr; 
        *headPtr = ( *headPtr )->proximoPtr;   
        free( tempPtr );
    } 
    int ehVazia( NodoPilhaPtr headPtr ){
        return headPtr == NULL;
    }
    void imprimePilha( NodoPilhaPtr atualPtr ){
        NodoPilhaPtr inicioPtr;
        inicioPtr=atualPtr;
        if ( atualPtr == NULL ) {
            puts( "Pilha esta vazia.\n" );
        } 
        else {
            puts( "A pilha eh:" );
            while ( atualPtr != NULL ) {
                printf( "%s --> ", atualPtr->nome );
                atualPtr = atualPtr->proximoPtr;
            } 
            puts( "NULL\n" );

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo a chamada? Ocorre algum erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você parece que quer criar um verificador de expressões aritméticas, certo? O código de fato compila, e compilando gera um executável. O problema é que esse executável, ao receber uma expressão válida como `a + b`, gera um erro de proteção.

Me parece que o erro é gerado pelo incremento da variável `i` na linha 29: quando o programa entra no *loop* da linha 28, `i` *já é* 1, e imediatamente incrementando, você faz com que o código ignore o primeiro argumento, fazendo com que o programa enxergue só `+ b`; além disso, da última vez que ele entrar o *loop*, o `i` será incrementado para ficar igual a `argc` e o sistema tentará empilhar `argv[argc]` que, segundo o padrão C, é `NULL`; ao tentarmos acessá-lo tomamos o erro.

Além disso, o código ainda não efetivamente faz verificação nenhuma, só empilha o primeiro argumento, o desempilha quando vê o segundo, empilha o terceiro, e por aí vai, até encontrar o fim dos argumentos e então retorna "Válida" ou "Não Válida" de acordo com se o programa recebeu um número ímpar ou par de argumentos.

Comment: O problema realmente estava na linha 28, o código eu terminei e fiz a modificação.. obg

Answer (score 1):

O `argc` (*argument count*) é um inteiro e possui o número de argumentos com os quais a função main() foi chamada na linha de comando.

O `argv` (*argument values*) é um vetor de strings. Cada string deste vetor é um dos parâmetros da linha de comando. É para saber quantos elementos temos em `argv` que temos `argc`.

**Exemplo:** O programa a seguir faz uso dos parâmentros argv e argc. O programa
recebe da linha de comando o dia, mês e ano correntes, e imprimi a data em formato apropriado.

Veja o exemplo, supondo que o executável se chame **`data`**:

```
data 26 03 88
```

O sistema terá a seguinte saída:

```
26 de Março de 1.988
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int mes;
    char *nomemes [] = {"Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho",
                        "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"};
    if(argc == 4)
    {
        mes = atoi(argv[2]);

        if (mes<1 || mes>12)
            printf("Erro!\nMes invalido!");
        else
            printf("\n%s de %s de 20%s", argv[1],

        nomemes[mes- 1], argv[3]);
    } else
        printf("Erro!\nUso: data dia mes ano, todos inteiros");
    }
```

**Fonte:** www.univasf.edu.br/~marcelo.linder/arquivos_pc/aulas/aula19.pdf